# R Error in rfe.defau: "there should be the same number of samples in x and y"

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I cannot get the caret rfe to work. Starting from a known, the example in http://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-the-caret-r-package/ works flawlessly.

As I substitute my own dataset though, it fails:

```
> results <- rfe(x, y, sizes=c(1:5), rfeControl=control)
Error in rfe.default(x, y, sizes = c(1:5), rfeControl = control) : 
  there should be the same number of samples in x and y
```

As far as I can tell, the number of sample rows in x and y are the same;

```
> nrow(x)
[1] 691231
> nrow(y)
[1] 691231
```

See below for details.

I've looked at similar questions, like [R rfe function "caret" Package error: there should be the same number of samples in x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441657/r-rfe-function-caret-package-error-there-should-be-the-same-number-of-samples) and [R trying to get caret / rfe to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143610/r-trying-to-get-caret-rfe-to-work). The latter is relevant, but it doesn't seem to help. I've tried converting my y to vector like

```
> y <- as.vector(y)
```

or

```
> y <- as.vector(as.list(y))
```

but the error persists. 
Surely I do something stupid, I just cannot see where I err. Any help is appreciated.

:-)

yarc

----------------------details--------------

------script--------

```
library(feather)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

path <- "faultclass.feather"
df <- read_feather(path)

set.seed(7)
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
x <- subset(df,select=-c(fault))
y <- df["fault"]*1
results <- rfe(x, y, sizes=c(1:5), rfeControl=control)
print(results)
predictors(results)
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

------characteristics------

```
> str(x)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   691231 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ A               : chr  "2011-12-06 00:00:00" "2011-03-11 00:00:00" "2014-11-17 00:00:00" "2013-01-07 15:19:02" ...
 $ B               : num  6 6 11 11 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ C               : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ D               : chr  "2016-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 00:00:00" ...
 $ E               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ F               : num  0 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 230 0 ...
 $ G               : num  13 35 38 128 12 6 10 4 2 6 ...
 $ H               : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ J               : chr  "35" "35" "28" "34" ...
 $ K               : num  0 63 32 63 40 40 35 40 35 25 ...
 $ L               : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 ...
 $ M               : num  301 301 301 301 301 301 301 301 301 301 ...
 $ N               : chr  "613.0" "9630.0" "9114.0" "600.0" ...
 $ O               : chr  "000356039" "000664676" "000770082" "000617804" ...
 $ P               : chr  "11610000" "0000003001" "1161000" "43850" ...
 $ Q               : num  10089 10089 10972 27629 27630 ...
 $ R               : num  7.07e+17 7.07e+17 7.07e+17 7.07e+17 7.07e+17 ...
 $ S               : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ T               : chr  "XX" "XX" "809" "96" ...
 $ U               : chr  "cac" "edr" "ssr" "nsk" ...
 $ V               : chr  "1954-05-17 00:00:00" "1973-05-17 00:00:00" "1997-06-24 00:00:00" "1976-12-24 00:00:00" ...
 $ W               : num  287 287 287 665 664 664 664 664 664 664 ...
 $ X               : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Y               : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Z               : num  24828 39591 8932 35162 28540 ...
 $ AA              : chr  "0001" "0001" "0001" "0002" ...
 $ AB              : chr  "0001-TRA" "0001-TRB" "0001-TRC" "0002-TRD" ...
 $ AC              : chr  "0,230" "0,230" "0,230" "0,230" ...
 $ AD              : chr  "K03" "K03" "K03" "K05" ...
 $ AE              : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ AF              : chr  "IT" "IT" "IT" "IT" ...

> str(y)
'data.frame':   691231 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fault: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually I got it to work by using

```
y = as.vector(unlist(c(y)))
```

I am not sure why this is different to

```
y = as.vector(y)
```

but this is what worked for me.