# FeatureTerminatoR's rfeTerminator function displays "should be the same number of samples" error

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

The new feature selection package **FeatureTerminatoR**'s *rfeTerminator* function displays "should be the same number of samples in x and y" error.

```
library(FeatureTerminatoR)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(randomForest)
tidymodels_prefer()

mtcars2 <- as_tibble(mtcars)

rfe_fit_col_name <- rfeTerminator(
    mtcars2, x_cols=2:ncol(mtcars2), 
    y_cols=1, 
    alter_df=TRUE)
```

> Error in rfe.default(df[, x_cols], df[, y_cols], sizes = c(sizes), rfeControl = ctrl,  :
> there should be the same number of samples in x and y

Answer (score 1):

Possibly similar to questions about the **caret** package's *rfe* function springing the same error, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022377/r-error-in-rfe-defau-there-should-be-the-same-number-of-samples-in-x-and-y), the input object for FeatureTerminatoR's *rfeTerminator* function is not of the needed class. Unlike other solutions on SO for *rfe*, what worked for *rfeTerminator* was to convert the input object to a normal data frame instead of a tibble.

What my reproducible example does not reflect is that some functions like *readxl::read_excel* will load the data as a tibble and one may not be aware of such.

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(mtcars2)

rfe_fit_col_name <- rfeTerminator(
    mtcars2, x_cols=2:ncol(mtcars2), 
    y_cols=1, 
    alter_df=TRUE)
```