# caret/rfe-error: "there should be the same number of samples in x and y"

Tags: r, validation, r-caret

My aim is to perform cross validation with R. Columns 1-31 are Features and column 32 is the output class. 
I load data from a .xls file.
But I have severe issues with the rfeControl-function. Please see my code:

```
install.packages('e1071')
library(e1071)
install.packages('readxl')
library(readxl)
library(rpart)
install.packages('randomForest')
library(randomForest)
install.packages('party')
library(party)
install.packages('mlbench')
library(mlbench)
install.packages('caret')
library(caret)
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Import Data
getwd()
setwd("working_directory_name")
df <- read_excel('test_data.xls')
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Get Information on your data (optional)
str(df)
table(df$F32)
#----------------------------------------------------------
install.packages('XLConnect')
library(XLConnect)
# Recursive Feature Selection Approach
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=5)
#x = as.vector(unlist(df[, 2:29]))
#y = as.vector(unlist(df[, 32])) 
# Run the algorithm (Features, Ground Truth, Testes SetSizes)
#results <- rfe(x, y, sizes=c(1:28), rfeControl=control)
results <- rfe(df[, 2:29], df[, 32], sizes=c(1:28), rfeControl=control)
# Visualize results for set sizes
print(results)
# List chosen features
predictors(results)
# plot the results
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

The result after running the code is:

> Fehler in rfe.default(df[, 2:29], df[, 32], sizes = c(1:28),
>   rfeControl = control) :    there should be the same number of samples
>   in x and y

I've already looked at these sites:
1. http://braziebrazie.blogspot.de/2015/08/caret-r-error-in-rfedefau-should-be.html
2. [R rfe function "caret" Package error: there should be the same number of samples in x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441657/r-rfe-function-caret-package-error-there-should-be-the-same-number-of-samples?rq=1)
3. [R trying to get caret / rfe to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143610/r-trying-to-get-caret-rfe-to-work)

The suggestion from 1. to unlist the vector doesn't work for me. The new error is:

> Fehler in if (nrow(x) != length(y)) stop("there should be the same
>   number of samples in x and y") :    Argument hat Länge 0

The example in 2. works without any problems:

```
set.seed(7)
d=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2901*15,1,.5),ncol=15))
#something like dependent variable
dp=factor(sample(c(1,1,1,1, 1, 1,2,2,2, 3 ,3,3,4, 4, 4),2901,replace = TRUE))
# define the control using a random forest selection function
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
# run the RFE algorithm
sz=50 # Change sz to 2901 for full sample
results <- rfe(d[1:sz, ],   dp[1:sz],   sizes=c(1:15), rfeControl=control)
# summarize the results
print(results)
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

In 3. it says

> y should be a numeric or factor vector

But how do I define this as numeric or factor vector?

This is the xls file format: [xls file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5uXl.png)

Maybe the problem is there because of the way I load the xls-file.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions and recommendations!

Comment: Do your columns all have the same amount of rows? Do you have NaN values in those rows? That's a first Thing you could check.

Comment: Yes, all columns have the same amount of rows. There is no NaN value in any row.

Comment: worked for me, please check 1st answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902732/caret-rfe-error-there-should-be-the-same-number-of-samples-in-x-and-y?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue.  Converted y to matrix and it worked.

```
results <- rfe(df[, 2:29], as.matrix(df[, 32]), sizes=c(1:28), rfeControl=control)
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify your call to `rfe` like so:

```
results <- rfe(df[, 2:29], df[[32]], sizes=c(1:28), rfeControl=control)
```

Note the change from single `[]` to double `[[]]` braces